# Accessing an object of a particular sub class from an array of abstract type objects

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting, object

I have a quick question.

I have a few classes, say Class SubA, SubB and SubC.
I also have an abstract class, lets say Parent

So I have an array of Parent objects, which contains instances of SubA, SubB and SubC.

I am basically trying to loop through the array or Parents and get a particular instance of SubA.

I have trieed the following but it produces a type exception:

```
foreach (SubA a in Parent.GetList())
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I try to use the OfType method, I get a compilation error as System.Array does not contian this method - I am guessing my method call GetList() through you off. It is just a simple array - is there an equivalent method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that current code has an implicit cast, which will fail if you've got an object of the "wrong" type in your collection. I suggest you use LINQ's [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) method:

```
using System.Linq; // Make LINQ extension methods available

...

foreach (SubA a in Parent.GetList().OfType<SubA>())
{
    ...
}
```

Note that `a` will never be null in the above - I'm assuming that's okay.

Comment: It is just a simple array, so it doesn't have the OfType method. Is there another way to do the same for an array?

Comment: @PectusExcavatum: Arrays implement `IEnumerable`, so so long as you have `using System.Linq;` it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that was my mistake. Thanks for your help; it is much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 5):

Use `OfType<T>` documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913.aspx).

```
foreach(SubA a in Parent.GetList().OfType<SubA>())
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a particular instance you can use the Single or SingleOrDefault extension methods on the array. Single will throw an exception if the collection does not contain a matching element; SingleOrDefault will return null.

If you are looking for one object of a certain type

```
var result = parents.Single(p => p is SubA);
```

If the objects have a key

```
var result = parents.Single(p => p is SubA and p.Id == id);
```

Or you supply whatever criteria allows you to identify the instance.